# Android - Stagefright framework consistency across devices/manufactures

Tags: android, h.264, stagefright

Is there any sort of guaranteed consistency in the use of `Stagefright` across manufacturers and/or devices?

Although Android introduced `Stagefright` in 2.x, is there anything that keeps manufacturers from making changes to it?  As of ICS, Android has officially [added native API support](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.0-highlights.html#DeveloperApis) for (at least a subset of) `OpenMAX AL 1.0.1`, but I would like to be able to support older devices.

I'm trying to get at `SEI` (`NAL`) user data from H.264 video, and I am trying to figure out the best way to get at it.  Is `Stagefright` a decent way to do it, or is it not guaranteed across devices?

Comment: "is there anything that keeps manufacturers from making changes to it?" Not really. As long as the device complies to Google's CDD and passes the operators' type approval tests, pretty much everything is fair game when it comes to making changes.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if decent but it is doable. If using sw dec you can catch SEI from within of h264bsd, otherway is to catch NAL from AAVCAssembler or other source, another issue is to where do you want to send grabbed SEI (or how - here this less decent part begins i guess).